# Find C and the distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The density distribution of $\xi$ is defined by:

$P_{\xi}(x)= \begin{cases} Cx^{-3/2} & \text{if } 1\leq x, \\ 0 & \text{if } x<1 \end{cases}$

Find C and the distribution function $F_{\xi}(x)$.

To find $C$ I have tried the following:

$1=P(\Omega)=\int_{1}^{\infty}Cx^{-3/2}=C\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{-3/2}=2C$

Thus $C=\frac{1}{2}$. This is correct?

Could you please help to find the distribution function? I'm not quite sure what to do to find it.

Answer (score 5):

C is correct. The cumulative distribution function will be $$F(x)=\int_1^x{\frac12x^{-3/2}}dx$$ so we will get an expression in terms of x

Answer (score 4):

Your $C$ value is correct.

If you are referring to the cumulative distribution function, we want to find
$P(X\leq x)=0$ if $x<1$

$P(X\leq x)=\int_1^x \frac{1}{2}x^{-3/2}$ for $x\geq 1$.

I will let you do the calculations, but the cumulative distribution function is integral of the probability density function over its domain because we want to find the probability that the random variable $X$ takes on a value less than or equal to $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Your $C$ is correct and you should have already completed the work to find the CDF.

**Hint:** You have used the fact that: $1=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} F_\xi(x)$

> $$\begin{align}F_\xi(x) ~=~& \int_1^x P_\xi(s)\operatorname d s \\~=~& C\int_1^x s^{-3/2}\operatorname d s \\ ~=~& C~{[-2s^{-1/2}]}_{s=1}^{s=x}\\ ~=~& C~(2-2x^{-1/2})\end{align}$$